# Set Binding for DataTemplate's elements programmatically

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, code-behind

I have such a template

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MemberCoefDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Name="CheckBox"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Name="TextBox"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And i use it in a grid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource MemberCoefDataTemplate}" />
```

I need to dynamically add columns to the grid. As Binding i use indexer property. So i need to set binding dynamically, because i don't know to which index bind to. When i just for test tried this

```
var column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
column.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["MemberCoefDataTemplate"];
TextBox tb = column.CellTemplate.FindName("TextBox", dg) as TextBox;
```

I got InvalidOperationException wit description:

> this operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied

Answer (score 0):

Usually to get the control during the setup time, you would have to call the method `LoadContent();`

I would therefore try `column.CellTemplate.LoadContent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full explanation about your problem (and a solution of course) written by Josh Smith [here](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-use-findname-with-a-contentcontrol/) on his blog.

Indeed this is the point where the `DataGridTemplateColumn` applies the `DataTemplate`:

```
private FrameworkElement LoadTemplateContent(bool isEditing, object dataItem, DataGridCell cell)
{
    DataTemplate dataTemplate;
    DataTemplateSelector dataTemplateSelector;
    this.ChooseCellTemplateAndSelector(isEditing, out dataTemplate, out dataTemplateSelector);
    if (dataTemplate != null || dataTemplateSelector != null)
    {
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentPresenter, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding());
        contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = dataTemplate;
        contentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector = dataTemplateSelector;
        return contentPresenter;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see a `ContentPresenter` is used.